# Tests are failing, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So, I've been trying to get this program to pass both test cases. I'm supposed to make a list that contains the character that follows each non-tail occurrence of a pattern in a text.

Here is the code...

```
    public static ArrayList<Character> getCharsThatFollowPattern (String text, String pattern)
    {

        ArrayList<Character> character = new ArrayList<Character>();

        int i = 0;
        while (i <= text.length())
        {
            int index = text.indexOf(pattern, i);
            if (index + pattern.length() < text.length())
            {

                character.add(text.charAt(index + pattern.length()));
            }

            i = i + text.indexOf(pattern, index) + pattern.length();

        }

        return character;
    }
```

Here are the test cases:

a) For this one, I get [b], but I'm supposed to get [b, b]

```
@Test(timeout = 2000)
   public void testGetCharsThatFollowPattern ()
   {
       ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
       list.add('b');
       list.add('b');
       ArrayList<Character> chars = PS5Library.getCharsThatFollowPattern("abababa", "aba");
       assertEquals(list, chars);
   }
```

b) For this one, I get [c, d] but I'm supposed to get [c, d, c]

```
 @Test(timeout = 2000)
    public void testGetCharsThatFollowPattern2 ()
    {
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        list.add('c');
        list.add('d');
        list.add('c');
        ArrayList<Character> chars = PS5Library.getCharsThatFollowPattern("abcabdabcab", "ab");
        assertEquals(list, chars);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at RegEx?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @jbx It's a bunch of methods that my teacher assigned. The code that I posted is part of this. The other methods in the PS5 library don't affect the method I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<Character> getCharsThatFollowPattern (String text, String pattern) {

  ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
  int index = text.indexOf(pattern);  
  while (index >= 0) {
    if (index + pattern.length() < text.length()) {
       characters.add(text.charAt(index + pattern.length()));
    }
    index = text.indexOf(pattern, index + 1);  
  }      

  return characters;
}
```

`index` will return `-1` when the pattern is not found any more, so you could use that as your check to exit the loop.

The second `indexOf()` is only doing `+ 1` due to the overlap you are expecting for `abababa`with pattern `aba` to return `b,b`.

Comment: I am getting `[b, b]` when I run it. Can you confirm you took the latest version?.

Comment: Lemmee try again

Comment: Cool. Follow through the code to understand what it is really doing though. I am sure the intention of your tutor was that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code finds all separate occurrences (which is normally what would be desired) but what you actually want is to find *all* occurrences including those that overlap. To do this, you need to make sure that you only move by one character on each iteration instead of moving by the length of the match.

```
public static ArrayList<Character> getCharsThatFollowPattern (String text, String pattern) {
    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        i = text.indexOf(pattern, i);
        if (i < 0) break;

        int charIndex = i + pattern.length();
        if (charIndex >= text.length()) break;
        characters.add(text.charAt(charIndex));
    }
    return characters;
}
```